# CNAME to Heroku app results in 301 redirect

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku

**TL;DR**: I want my custom domain to be shown in the address bar, not the CNAME.

I have an app hosted on Heroku at [try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com](http://try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com).

I bought the domain from Namecheap, and configured the CNAME entry there:

```
www.tryelixir.online CNAME try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com.
```

I also configured the custom domains in heroku:

```
 $ heroku domains
=== try-elixir-phoenix Heroku Domain
try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com

=== try-elixir-phoenix Custom Domains
Domain Name           DNS Target
────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────
tryelixir.online      try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com
www.tryelixir.online  try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com
```

But if I curl my custom domain, I get a 301 redirect:

```
 $ curl --head http://www.tryelixir.online
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Cowboy
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 15:11:01 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Location: https://try-elixir-phoenix.herokuapp.com/
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

This also means that the user sees the `herokuapp.com` URL, instead of my custom one.

The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domain) say that:

> Your app’s Heroku Domain will always remain active, even if you’ve set
>   up a custom domain. If you want users to use the custom domain
>   exclusively, your app should send HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently to
>   tell web browsers to use the custom domain. The Host HTTP request
>   header field will show which domain the user is trying to access; send
>   a redirect if that field is example.herokuapp.com.

Does the above apply to me?

Comment: No, that is the inverse of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the redirect was happening at the app level. Heroku's support confirmed that their router doesn't add any redirects.

Comment: which file was the redirect happening within the application? And how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the [instructions](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku) then before adding your custom domain the you'll need to update the config:

```
url: [scheme: "https", host: "mysterious-meadow-6277.herokuapp.com", port: 443], force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, there is a quick (yet insecure) solution. If your application is handling any sensitive data for example credit card information or user login details then **DO NOT** use this method but instead set up your application to work with SSL.

### --- Insecure solution ---

You should have something like this in your config/prod.exs file:

```
# config/prod.exs 

config :app, App.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "app.herokuapp.com", port: 443],
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")
```

You want to make the following changes:

1. Change the url scheme from https to http
2. Remove the force_ssl configuration

This should leave you something like this:

```
# config/prod.exs 

config :app, App.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "http", host: "app.herokuapp.com", port: 443],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")
```

On your next redeploy you should be able to visit your application at your custom domain.